# Transition matrix as a feature to feed machine learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, svm, k-nearest-neighbour, recommender-system

Currently, I am trying to replicate a paper to extend the research on the paper they create a transition matrix similar to this one:

[image]

**my question is** : how can I feed this information into my KNN or SVM algorithms?

As far as I understand they only receive columns with continuous or discrete data, I was suggested to flat the matrix. Nonetheless it seems the authors of the paper opt for a different approach.

Here are some passages from the paper:

> We normalize the chord transition matrices by the total number of
> chord transitions so that each element represents the probability of
> the chord transition.
>
> We discretize the musical features and emotions while 2-chord, 3-chord
> matrix, and chord histogram are used as binary data regarding non-zero
> value as one.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you hope your algorithms will do and what role do you want this information to play?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I would like to cluster similar patterns of sequences of data.. so for example:  c#,c#,f,a is more or less similar to c# c#d,a, f. So I was hoping to map these patterns into these transitions matrix to latter use a clustering algorithm. @whuber